# shut down and reboot into windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, boot

I am running windows 8 on C, and have an old windows 7 on D.  When I orinally installed windows 8 I had a 5 second bootup screen offering if I wanted windows 7 or 8.  I removed this so now it only boots into windows 8.  I use windows 7 very rarely but still want the ability to do this.

In system configuration I can set D as my default, but I want a simple button to press that will boot into windows 7 once, and not change any settings.  I seem to remember seeing options like this when I removed the boot screen.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

advanced startup is needed.

windows+I to bring up side panel and into change PC settings.

8.1 its under update and recovery>recovery> advanced start-up >restart now

will bring up a menu for one off boot options